# Google Play Console App Review Rejects the prior version of the app

Tags: google-play-console

I'm trying to deploy an updated version of my app (lets call this version 5.4.1) to Google Play Console for the purposes of Open Testing. This new version will replace the current in-production version 5.4.0.

Version 5.4.0 has a severe bug during login that prevents all users from going any further.
Version 5.4.1 fixes this issue.

We have provided Google with the necessary login information as part of the app review process.

Google Play rejects the app saying that they are unable to login, but interestingly the message says that they were testing **5.4.0** as opposed to 5.4.1.

This is my first time deploying an app to Play Console, so not sure what is going on. Does Google review the prior version as well as part of the review process for a newer version?

I've checked and double checked that 5.4.1 does fix the issue AND that v5.4.1 is the one I've asked for a review, etc.

Not sure what is happening, anybody have any hints?